# Add tooltip to Excel Add-in Custom Ribbon UI XML

Tags: excel-2010, add-in, ribbonx

I am creating an Excel Add-In that has a custom Ribbon UI. I would like to add a tooltip for my buttons. What XML attributes can I use to set this?

```
<button id="insertStuff" label="Insert Stuff" size="large" onAction="InsertStuff_EventHandler" imageMso="AddAccount" />
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use "screentip" and "supertip":

```
<button id="insertStuff" screentip="Tooltip title" supertip="Long description" ...
```

BTW, you should have autocomplete normally when you edit the ribbon XML in VS.
If you don't make sure you have Ribbon schema file available.